# Has anyone been able to skin the Flex Mobile actionBar to look just like the dark theme Android ICS Action bar?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5, flex-mobile

(In regards to Flex Mobile AIR on Android apps)

Has anyone been able to skin the Flex Mobile actionBar to look just like the dark theme Android ICS Action bar?

if so, how could you skin this using all mxml?

Or if anyone has seen an android "theme" for flex mobile

Answer (score 1):

On the mobile applications it is typically recommended to not use MXML skins as they are too heavy and cause performance issues. If you look at all the mobile skins they are actually written with straight actionscript and are very low level.

The good news is the Actionbar in ICS is very minimal and just has a black background and some icons. You could actually set the chrome color CSS property to black and get very close. Alternatively you could write an AS skin for the navigation bar and navigation buttons and have no content.